# Как убрать arrow с сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Как убрать с сайта стрелки лево и вправо. http://eranewgames.ru/

Я не могу понять в каком месте они лежат. В Html их нет. Остается только js или css.

Где найти код отвечающий за действие и отображение стрелок? чтобы я смогу убрать их и заменить на свои

Comment: .tparrows { display: none; }

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, Куда это вписать? 
А можно сделать так что бы стрелка осталась но не двигалась?

Comment: Это пишется в стилях. А вообще, rewolution slider настраивается и из админки.

Comment: @xTIGRx, не могли бы добавить какой-нибудь релевантный код в вопрос? На сайте, как я понимаю стрелок давно нет..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убрать навигацию можно из административной части, зайдите в настройки плагина, Revolution Slider > settings или настройки смотря какая локализация далее навигация > навигационные стрелки и выберайте занчение. 
Либо через css  .tparrows { display: none; }, ниже есть поля для ввода custom css/javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Если у стрелки есть Класс или ID
то так JS

```
a = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-class");
a[0].style.display = 'none';
```